# What allows us to treat physical units in algebra?

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, si-units

I have been thinking about this problem:

$$Speed = \frac{Distance}{Time}$$

Following this, is makes sense that the units of speed is m/s. However, I do not follow why we are able to divide units to derive a new unit, which turns out to be intuitive later on (e.g. meter/second gives you 'meter per second' which makes intuitive sense as a unit of speed).

Comment: You are over-thinking this.  The unit follows from the definition of speed.  They don't "turn out to be intuitive later on", they start out as being just as intuitive as the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about the exact nature of your question. When you divide units, you are forming a *ratio* of two quantities. Often, these quantities are things we know how to or would like to measure. So when you divide distance by time, you get a ratio of one quantity you can measure (distance) and another quantity you can measure (time) which is meaningful.

This can actually end up being a useful thing to do in physics, and is known as [Dimensional Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing dimensions and units. Dimensions group together co-measurable units. For example 5 seconds from now (second is a unit of measure) is $\frac{1}{12}$ minutes from now where the conversion made is multiplication by dimensionless quantity.

Another example: In Special relativity due to nature of $c$ and/or the identification (up to an important sign) of spacial and temporal units having the same dimension renders velocity dimensionless:

If I can measure potential gravitational energy with a ladder and a ruler and convert it to a mass using division by a velocity, then these are co measurable as well, etc.